# How to create test on a non inline style CSS in a jest

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

Is there a way to test a non inline style CSS color of the word 'Hello' in a jest?

```
.textStyle {
 color: red;
}

<p class="textStyle">Hello</p>

test('test text color', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<React />);
    const p = wrapper.find('p').text();
    //insert code here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**For that, you would use a regular `getBy` or `findBy` or any selectors and use a `toHaveStyle` accordingly**

```
expect(getByTestId('elementId')).toHaveStyle('color: red')
```

You will also need to install [jest-dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom) to have [toHaveStyle](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohavestyle) available

Comment: is this applicable for testing external css styles?

Answer (score 0):

You might find some success with the [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) API. Calling this with an element gives you an object of that elements styles, which you can then verify have the correct values.

Comment: is this applicable for testing external css styles?

Comment: Yes, regardless of where the styles come from, this API will tell you which styles the element has applied to it right now. The same goes for the assertion suggested by Ryan Le, using jest-dom (it probably uses getComputedStyle in the background).

Comment: No, it doesn't work for non inline styles. I tested and it doesn't work when style is declared in scss file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75777333/jest-shows-element-has-block-as-display-value